# How to properly add a child object to a parent's collection using rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following two models: Blueprint and Workload.
The Blueprint model instance should have a collection of Workloads associated with it.
Initially, bot the Blueprint and Workload instances should be allowed to be created independently.
A complete typical scenario as follows:

1) a new Blueprint instance is created

2) a new Workload instance is created

3) the created Workload instance is added to the Blueprint's 'workloads' collection

The python REPL version is this:

```
blueprint = Blueprint(name="bluepint 1")
blueprint.save()
workload = Workload)name="workload 1")
workload.save()
blueprint.workloads.add(blueprint)
blueprint.save()
```

In my python client, I am able to create the instances of the Blueprint and Workload independently, and without issue.

My question is: what is the proper HTTP method and the corresponding URL syntax, to add a Workload to the Blueprint's 'workloads' collection.

Here is the models.py:

```
class Workload(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, default='')
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, default='')
    flavor = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, default='')
    blueprint = models.ForeignKey('Blueprint', related_name='workloads', null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        unique_together = ('blueprint', 'name')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%d: %s' % (self.name, self.description)


class Blueprint(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, default='')
    description = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
```

And here is the serializers.py:

```
# region Workload Serializer
class WorkloadSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    pk = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    name = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True, max_length=120)
    description = serializers.CharField(style={'type': 'textarea'})
    image = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True, max_length=120)
    flavor = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True, max_length=120)


    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        Create and return a new `Snippet` instance, given the validated data.
        """
        return Workload.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        """
        Update and return an existing `Snippet` instance, given the validated data.
        """
        instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name)
        instance.description = validated_data.get('description', instance.description)
        instance.image = validated_data.get('image', instance.image)
        instance.flavor = validated_data.get('flavor', instance.flavor)
        instance.save()
        return instance
# endregion


# region Blueprint Serializer
class BlueprintSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    workloads = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True, required=False)
    pk = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    name = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True, max_length=120)
    description = serializers.CharField(style={'type': 'textarea'})

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        Create and return a new `Snippet` instance, given the validated data.
        """
        return Blueprint.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        """
        Update and return an existing `Snippet` instance, given the validated data.
        """
        instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name)
        instance.description = validated_data.get('description', instance.description)
        instance.save()
        return instance

    class Meta:
        model = Blueprint
        fields = ('name', 'description', 'workloads')
# endregion
```

-Eugene

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an REST expert, but in terms of REST i believe your urls should look like that:

```
GET  /api/blueprint/                #list the blueprints
POST /api/blueprint/                #add new blueprint
GET  /api/blueprint/1/              #detail information about blueprint with id=1
PUT  /api/blueprint/1/              #update blueprint with id=1
GET  /api/blueprint/1/workloads/    #list all workloads of blueprint with id 1
POST /api/blueprint/1/workloads/    #add new workload to blueprint with id 1 workloads
GET  /api/blueprint/1/workloads/1   #detail information about workload with id=1 and blueprint id = 1
PUT  /api/blueprint/1/workloads/1   #update information about workload with id=1 and blueprint id = 1
```

So your repl exmaple in `REST` contex is going to look like:

```
#request
http POST /api/blueprint/ name="bluepint 1"

#response
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "bluepint 1",
    "description": ""
}

#request
http POST /api/blueprint/1/workloads/ name="workload 1"

#response
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "workload 1",
    "description": "",
    "image": "",
    "flavor": "",
    "blueprint": 1
}
```

In order to make such url structure, u should checkout [drf-extensions](http://chibisov.github.io/drf-extensions/docs/#nested-routes) or [drf-nested-routers](https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers)

Another approach would be to add custom `detail` endpoint to `/api/blueprint/`, something like:

```
http POST /api/blueprint/1/add_workload/ name="workload 2"
```

If u use Viewsets, this is going to loook like this:

```
#inside BlueprintViewset
@detail_route(methods=['post'])
def add_workload(self, request, pk):
    serializer = WorkloadSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save(blueprint=pk)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```